# JetPack Compose HorizontalPager in LazyColumn does not retain focus when using TalkBack

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, talkback, horizontal-pager

We have a JetPack Compose HorizontalPager as one of many elements in a LazyColumn. The HorizontalPager has left and right pointing arrow buttons on each side to move to the previous or next item using animateScrollToPage. When using TalkBack and tapping the buttons, the focus will not stay on the items inside the HorizontalPager.

We are expecting TalkBack to read the next item in the HorizontalPager and for the focus to remain on the items in the Pager. We have tried applying the .focusable Modifier, .semantics, and .focusGroup at various levels in the code that wraps the HorizontalPager, and the Pager itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.